# Invalidating a minyan

Tags: kaddish, minyan, cherem

Hypothetical case --
I am within my year of saying kaddish and am on a business trip. I am in a very small and unfamiliar shul waiting for a minyan and in walks someone from my town who has been placed in [seruv](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31808/what-is-the-punishment-for-receiving-a-seruv-from-a-bais-din) to a degree that he should not be counted in a minyan.

What is my obligation in terms of "telling on him" if it will (might?) destroy the opportunity for davening (b'zman) with a minyan and my opportunity to say kaddish. Are there mitigating factors or other variables which might guide my (in)actions?

Comment: Did the seruv say it wasn't meant to cause someone to not say kaddish? Why would you think it wasn't designed to apply in exactly this case like any other?

Comment: You would do more for the Neshama by following the Siruv, than by saying Kadish.

Comment: but I would also be stopping others from davening with a minyan (are there levels of obligation in conflict here?)

Comment: You are helping others not Daven with one they should not be Davening with.

Comment: But would the rabbinic edict be measured up against the requirement to daven with a minyan?

Comment: The requirement to daven with a minyan is also Rabbinic.

Comment: rosends, you are giving lots of reasons you or someone might disagree with a decision to issue a seruv (costs may out-weigh benefits), but none for why you would think it wasn't designed to apply in exactly this case like any other.